# create a table with test results. Apply instead of loop

Tags: r, apply, sapply

I want to run wilcox.test multiple times on different groupings based on dummy variables. 
I have a dataset that has columns for Revenue and then a series of dummy variables.

Ideally I want a table like this as a result. I want this just to have a quick way to see which variables are important to look at more closely. I have 100+ dummy variables.

```
Variable   p-value
dummy1     0.052
dummy2     0.143
dummy3     0.001
```

I know that this should be possible using apply, or sapply. But I am not sure how to to go about doing this.

For the moment I am running through it using a loop, but it's not very practical because the the results are not labelled with the dummy variable name or number.

```
list <- list(data$dummy1, data$dummy2, data$dummy3, .....)
for (i in 1:100){
  print(wilcox.test(data$Revenue ~ list[[i]]) )
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't set an object names 'list'.  This could cause a conflict with `list`.

Try this:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(Revenue = rnorm(100, mean=1000, sd=100), dummy1 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE), dummy2 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE), dummy3 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE))

l <- list(data$dummy1, data$dummy2, data$dummy3)
names(l) <- names(data[,2:ncol(data)])

out <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(l, FUN = function(x) wilcox.test(data$Revenue ~ x)$p.value, USE.NAMES = TRUE)))
rownames(out) <- "Revenue"


# The output
          dummy1   dummy2    dummy3
Revenue 0.975232 0.689687 0.1830813
```

If you are want multiple variables:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(Profits = rnorm(100, mean=1000, sd=100), Revenue = rnorm(100, mean=1000, sd=100), dummy1 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE),
                   dummy2 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE), dummy3 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE))
l <- list(data$dummy1, data$dummy2, data$dummy3)

#Vector of variables of interest
vec <- c("Revenue", "Profits")
names(l) <- names(data)[!names(data) %in% vec]

out <- t(sapply(vec, FUN = function(y) sapply(l, FUN = function(x) wilcox.test(data[,c(y)] ~ x)$p.value, simplify=F)))
out

        dummy1    dummy2    dummy3   
Revenue 0.8491605 0.3425132 0.1765484
Profits 0.1830813 0.1951    0.5036012
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still getting the hang of R. 

Would I have to use a different apply function if I wanted to add another row like Profits?

Comment: @Constantin, if you want to multiple variables you would need a second sapply statement and a vector of the variable you wish to test.  `vec <- c("Revenue", "Profits")` Then you can loop over these as well.  `out <- t(sapply(vec, FUN = function(y) sapply(l, FUN = function(x) wilcox.test(data[,c(y)] ~ x)$p.value, simplify=F)))`

Comment: @charles Naming an object `list` will never conflict with `list(...)`

Comment: @SeñorO My mistake, but thank you for the clarification.  It is still generally good practice to not name an object the same as a function.